# Set caret inside contenteditable div after inserted element

Tags: javascript, firefox, range, contenteditable, caret

I am trying to make my application run on all browsers and I need to position the caret inside a contenteditable div just after the text selected from a pop-up by the user. So far my application is working on IE, but I need to also make it work on Opera, Firefox and Chrome.
My Javascript code for placing the caret on IE looks like this:

```
  function setCaretPos()
  {
     if (document.selection) 
     {
         /* IE */
         var range = document.body.createTextRange();
         range.moveToElementText(editableDiv);
         var insertedSpan = document.getElementById('span' + count);
         var preCaretRange = document.body.createTextRange();
         preCaretRange.moveToElementText(insertedSpan);
         preCaretRange.moveEnd("character", 2);
         range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", preCaretRange);
         range.collapse(false);
         range.select();
      }
      else
      {
         if (window.getSelection) {
         /* Firefox, Opera, Chrome */
         var sel = window.getSelection();
         if(sel.rangeCount)
         {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var insertedSpan = document.getElementById('span' + count);
            var pos = insertedSpan.innerHTML.length;
            range.selectNodeContents(insertedSpan);
            range.setEndAfter(insertedSpan);
            range.collapse(false);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
         }
      }
 }
```

As you can see, on IE I am using the function moveEnd to move the range end with 2 characters to the right, but I do not know if there is any equivalent for this function on non IE browsers to move the end of the range with a specific number of chars. 
Using the code above, the text inside the span gets selected, but my problem is that the caret is not showing up after the inserted span, it simply disappers.

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you moving the caret two characters forward in IE?